# Why is the json object valid against this conditional schema?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Here is the json object.

```
{
  "payment": {
    "account": [
      {
        "type": "ACCOUNT_INFORMATION",
        "identification": "2451114"
      },
      {
        "type": "XXX",
        "identification": "2451114"
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

And this is the schema.

```
{
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "payment": {
        "properties": {
          "account": {
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "type": {
                  "const": "ACCOUNT_INFORMATION"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "payment": {
        "properties": {
          "account": {
            "items": {
              "properties": {
                "identification": {
                  "maxLength": 8,
                  "minLength": 8
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If remove the second account items as follows, the schema gives error.

```
{
  "payment": {
    "account": [
      {
        "type": "ACCOUNT_INFORMATION",
        "identification": "2451114"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this due to the conditional schema cannot be apply to an embedded array?

Validation used https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

The first json object returns no error while the second one returns error with violation of minLength constraint.

Should both return error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what's happening, let's break down the schema to focus on the critical part of the `if` schema.

```json
"items": {
  "properties": {
    "type": { "const": "ACCOUNT_INFORMATION" }
  }
}
```

Given this schema, the following instance is not valid because not all "type" properties have the value "ACCOUNT_INFORMATION".

```json
[
  {
    "type": "ACCOUNT_INFORMATION",
    "identification": "2451114"
  },
  {
    "type": "XXX",
    "identification": "2451114"
  }
]
```

And, this following value is valid because all "type" properties have the value "ACCOUNT_INFORMATION".

```json
[
  {
    "type": "ACCOUNT_INFORMATION",
    "identification": "2451114"
  }
]
```

That difference in validation result is the reason these two values behave differently in your schema. The `then` schema is applied only when the `if` schema evaluates to true, which is what you get with the second example and not the first. The `then` schema is applied on the second example and the `minLength` constraint causes validation to fail.

It seems like your conditional only applies to the `items` schema, so you can solve this by moving your conditional into that object only.

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "payment": {
      "properties": {
        "account": {
          "items": {
            "if": {
              "properties": {
                "type": {
                  "const": "ACCOUNT_INFORMATION"
                }
              },
              "required": ["type"]
            },
            "then": {
              "properties": {
                "identification": {
                  "maxLength": 8,
                  "minLength": 8
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```